# can we check client certificate of same root ca against multiple crl servers (that each crl generated by same rootca )?

Tags: networking

Certificates having 2 crl distribution point both signed by same root ca.
What should be crl fetch behaviour?

Crl fetched should be concated or overwritten?

can we check client certificate of same root ca against multiple crl servers (that each  crl generated by same rootca )?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether they're separate distribution points, or whether they're just separate URLs in the same distribution point.

My interpretation of [RFC 5280 section 4.2.1.13](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.13) and [section 5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-5):

- A single "CRL Distribution Points" extension may have multiple DistributionPoint items pointing to different CRLs, possibly with different ReasonFlags (e.g. one CRL for superseded certificates, another CRL for compromised, even though the spec recommends against this) – therefore you need to check *all* DistributionPoints and concatenate the results.
- But a single DistributionPoint may have multiple names (URLs) pointing to the same CRL. These act as *alternatives* (e.g. redundancy or multiple protocols), and you only need to check one URL for each DistributionPoint.

  > If the DistributionPointName contains multiple values, each name
  > describes a different mechanism to obtain the same CRL.  For example,
  > the same CRL could be available for retrieval through both LDAP and
  > HTTP.

So for example, if you have a CRL DP extension with:

```
CRLDistributionPoints {
    DistributionPoint {
        fullName [ URI "http://foo/foo.crl", URI "ldap://foo/foo.crl" ]
    },
    DistributionPoint {
        fullName [ URI "http://foo/bar.crl", URI "ldap://foo/bar.crl" ]
    }
}
```

then you would need to check two CRLs total: any one "foo.crl" + any one "bar.crl".